# Probleme with visual studio and Asp.net mvc3 project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging

I have a .js file to deal with a dialog box whatever when I use the java console to track errors, the java console shows always the same content of the .js file, I tried with IE,firefox and chrome I have the same problème
I tried to delete completely the .js file but still show the error in the file !!!
where is the problème ????
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a some problem with the syntax error or some other reference JS file is not included in a code. If you deleting that JS file and it's relative code, than still you need to clear your cache of the browser. It might be taking that JS file from the Cache. Please provide code here to resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug and check if you have syntax errors.